# Adding a range to an existing PrintArea with VBA fails with error 400

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to extend the current print area of my Excel sheet but currently, with the following code. It breaks at the third `.PageSetup.PrintArea` and I don't know why.

The code:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$A$5"

    MsgBox (.PageSetup.PrintArea & "," & .Cells(8, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(10, 1).Address)
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = .PageSetup.PrintArea & "," & .Cells(8, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(10, 1).Address

    MsgBox (.PageSetup.PrintArea & "," & .Cells(15, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(20, 1).Address)
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = .PageSetup.PrintArea & "," & .Cells(15, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(20, 1).Address
End With
```

On the last line it puts me an "Error 400" and I don't know why, it's exactly the same line as above. I also tried with `;` instead of `,` but it don't figure it out. If you have any ideas, please tell me, I'll be glad to ear it. 
Thanks, Clément

Comment: Ok, It works, but that's not what I wanted. Indeed, I want A1:A5 and then A8:A10 ... and not A1:A10. Ask me if you don't understand.

Comment: Try just **`& Chr(44) &`** 44 for `,` 58 for `:`

Comment: With Chr(44), still Error 400 ....

Comment: In locales where comma is not the list delimiter, `PageSetup.PrintArea` returns a string using A1-style references in the language of the locale. So your second `PageSetup.PrintArea` will be `$A$1:$A$5;$A$8:A$10` if semicolon is the list delimiter. But setting `PageSetup.PrintArea` needs always comma as the list delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect your Windows is set to use a list separator which is NOT the comma. In my case, the printarea property returns this after the second line of code (note the semi-colon):

```
$A$1:$A$5;$A$8:$A$10
```

But in order to set this printarea, the ; must be replaced with a comma:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$A$5,$A$8:$A$10"
```

So -on my system- for your code to work, I needed to use:

```
.PageSetup.PrintArea = Replace(.PageSetup.PrintArea, ";", ",") & "," & .Cells(15, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(20, 1).Address
```

Comment: You made my day ! Thanks, Clément.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.Union` ([Application.Union Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx)):

```
.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(.Range("$A$1:$A$5"), .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(10, 1)), .Range(.Cells(15, 1), .Cells(20, 1))).Address
```

to join all 3 ranges.

---

Or use

```
.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(.Range("Print_Area"), .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(10, 1))).Address
```

to add a range to an existing print area.
Here we use the fact that the existing print area is saved as a named range `Print_Area` which we can access by `.Range("Print_Area")`.

> *In case anoyne is suspect of how the English name `Print_Area` would behave in localized Office versions, we won't run into any issues because `Print_Area` always works even if the name manager shows the localized name of `Print_Area`.*

Comment: Still does not work...

 `With ActiveSheet
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$A$5"
         MsgBox (.PageSetup.PrintArea)
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(.Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea), .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(10, 1))).Address
        MsgBox (.PageSetup.PrintArea)
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(.Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea), .Range(.Cells(15, 1), .Cells(20, 1))).Address
        MsgBox (.PageSetup.PrintArea)
  End With` .

There's an error 400, at the same place (last .PageSetup.PrintArea = ...)

Comment: Because my goal isn't to join all at one time. My goal is to join every Range when I need it to ...

Comment: Added a fixed version to add a range to an existing print area

Comment: @Souin, check the length of the string being assigned to `Print_Area`. If its length is more than 255, 400 is occurred. Which is more important, `Range.Address` returns only the first 255 characters without any warnings!